# Line break (<br/>) within a header (<h2>) tag

Tags: html, css

Inserting a `br` tag within a header tag (e.g. `h2`) inserts a space after the first word.

How do I remove that space as I am right-aligning the text?

e.g.

```
<h2>
    hello
    <br/>
    world
</h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4er7r/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It isn't the `br` tag itself, but the returns surrounding it. They are translated to whitespace. Use this:

```
<h2>
    hello<br/>world
</h2>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4er7r/3/